# Can someone let me know linearity, time-invariance, causality, memory characteristic of the system?

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems

The input/output system is
$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+2y(t)=2x^2(t)
$$

---

I want to know this is linear? causal? time-invariant? memoryless?

According to solution, the answer is 'Linear if zero initial conditions, causal, time-invariant, with memory'.

---

My trial:

$$y(t)=x^2(t)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}$$

[image]

Sorry for my poor drawing.

---

1. for input value: $x_1(t)=2x(t)$,
   \begin{align}
   y_1(t)&=\left(2x(t)\right)^2+\left(-\frac12\right)\frac{d}{dt}\left(y(t)\right)\\
   &=4x^2(t)-\frac12\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\\
   2y(t)&=2x^2(t)-\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\\
   \therefore y_1(t) &\ne 2y(t)
   \end{align}

   ### $\because$ not satisfying Homogeneity, Non-Linear.

---

2. The system doesn't have $x(t+k)$. (It means $y(t)$ is not made by $x(t+k)$)

### $\therefore$ The system is causal because

---

3. for input value: $x_1(t)=x(t-t_0)$,
   \begin{align}
   y_1(t)&=x^2(t-t_0)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\\
   y(t-t_0)&=x^2(t-t_0)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy(t-t_0)}{dt}\\
   \therefore y_1(t) &\ne y(t-t_0)
   \end{align}

   ### $\therefore$ time-varying.
4. The system doesn't have any $\displaystyle\int$.

   i.e.) $\displaystyle\int x(\tau) d\tau$.

   ### $\therefore$ memoryless

---

What is the real solution?

Comment: whoa, the system is not linear (you're right about that), but it **is** time-invariant and it is **not** memoryless.

Comment: @johnson Thanks for a comment. Can you tell me why it is?

Comment: Where can I read about how to do this analysis on continuous systems? I already understand discrete systems.

Comment: This problem is in the text book, named "Continuous And Discrete Signals And Systems 2/e - Soliman and Srinath".

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your 3rd section (linearity) - you replace $y(t)$ with $y_1(t)$ on the left side of the equation but not on the right side. You should have
$$y_1(t)=x^2(t-t_0)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dy_1(t)}{dt}$$.
Now you see that $y_1(t)=y(t-t_0)$.

As for memoryless - start with your initial equation and integrate both sides. Now you have
$$
\int y(t)dt=\int x^2(t)dt-\frac{1}{2} y(t)dt
$$

and rearranging gives
$$
y(t) = 2 \int x^2(t)dt-2 \int y(t)dt
$$
Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got my fault, thanks to you. I should have to change $y(t)$ to $y_1(t)$. I think, I have to study differential equation first. I don't know how to find $y(t)$ from differential equation (I know a little.). I've booked introduction to differential equation textbook.